# SymPy para la resolucion de un sistema de ecuaciones y sustitución de simbolos por valores numéricos

Tags: python, matemáticas, sympy

Estoy usando el paquete `SymPy` (no me importaría usar otro si funciona como quiero) para la resolucion de un sistema de ecuaciones. El sistema contiene la unidad imaginaria `I` y unos coeficientes `p,q,r,c,w` que quiero mantener como constantes para las variables `n` y `N`. Estoy interesado en obtener la solucion y posteriormente sustituir valores en `p,q,r,s,w`.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import re, im, I, E, symbols

I = complex(0,1)
p = sym.symbols('p', real=True)
q = sym.symbols('q', real=True)
r = sym.symbols('r', real=True)
c = sym.symbols('c', real=True)
w = sym.symbols('w', real=True)

n, N = sym.symbols('n, N')
Eq1 = sym.Eq(p*n-q*(N*r-n)-c + w*n*I, 0)
Eq2 = sym.Eq(q*(N*r-n) + w*N*I, 0)
Sol = sym.solve([Eq1, Eq2], (n, N))

n = sym.simplify(Sol[n])
N = sym.simplify(Sol[N])

n_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(n))
n_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(n))
N_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(N))
N_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(N))

p=1
q=1
r=1
c=1

print('Re(n) =', n_real)
print('Im(n) =', n_imag)
```

el cual me da una solución:

```
Re(n) = c*(q*r*(p*q*r - w**2) + w**2*(p + q*r + q))/(w**2*(p + q*r + q)**2 + (p*q*r - w**2)**2)
Im(n) = c*w*(p*q*r - q*r*(p + q*r + q) - w**2)/(w**2*(p + q*r + q)**2 + (p*q*r - w**2)**2)
```

A esta solución he llegado igualmente resolviéndolo a mano. No obstante, me gustaría saber como reemplazar los valores de  `p,q,r,c` por un valor numérico cualquiera (ej.: `= 1`). Desafortunadamente, siempre obtengo el mismo output.

¿Sabe alguien porqué ocurre esto?¿Algún otro paquete que pueda realizar esta operación?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `.subs(diccionario)`:

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy import re, im, I, E, symbols

I = complex(0,1)
p = sym.symbols('p', real=True)
q = sym.symbols('q', real=True)
r = sym.symbols('r', real=True)
c = sym.symbols('c', real=True)
w = sym.symbols('w', real=True)

n, N = sym.symbols('n, N')
Eq1 = sym.Eq(p*n-q*(N*r-n)-c + w*n*I, 0)
Eq2 = sym.Eq(q*(N*r-n) + w*N*I, 0)
Sol = sym.solve([Eq1, Eq2], (n, N))

n = sym.simplify(Sol[n])
N = sym.simplify(Sol[N])

n_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(n))
n_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(n))
N_real = sym.simplify(sym.re(N))
N_imag = sym.simplify(sym.im(N))

subs_dic ={p: 1, q : 1, r : 1, c : 1}

print('Re(n) =', n_real.subs(subs_dic)) # (2*w**2 + 1)/(9*w**2 + (1 - w**2)**2)
print('Im(n) =', n_imag.subs(subs_dic)) # w*(-w**2 - 2)/(9*w**2 + (1 - w**2)**2)
```